# jQuery position() and PhantomJS

Tags: jquery, jasmine, phantomjs, karma-runner

I'm currently running a Jasmine spec that checks the DOM position of some elements after running some logic on them.  Works in all browsers except PhantomJS, which returns NaN for both .left and .top on any .position() call.  Has anyone else seen this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it wasn't the position() call after all, it was a previous call using css "calc".  This CSS function is not supported in QTWebkit, which PhantomJS uses.  Worth knowing.

Comment: Hi, what should i use instead of position() function? I'm trying to get the position of some DOM elements but the shadomjs it is not considering the padding.